# how can I get the setting of an object made by three.js

Tags: three.js

[image]

When I put a gltf file into the threejs editor, wow, it looks amazing.

[image]

But when I try to implment it, emmm, so terrible.

So, is it possible to get the setting from threejs editor?

For example, how the scene is setted? how about the render? is there any other setting?

Or, I only have to read the document step by step?

Comment: I recommend you start by [reading the "Getting Started" section in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene). They provide several examples and explanations on how to set up a boilerplate Three.js app. For example, your screenshot seems to need anti-aliasing and higher renderer resolution, all of which is covered in the "Getting Started" section of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it possible to get the setting from threejs editor?

There is no way to export the settings of the editor in some way. You actually have to study the implementation of the editor, especially the app player component. This component is responsible for rendering the 3D scene which you are seeing in the editor's viewport. You can find the source code for this file right here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/libs/app.js

However, I suggest you study one of the official glTF examples instead which provide a complete scene setup in much more approachable manner. Try it with:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf

Comment: thanks a lot！ this sample really helps!

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.